# IntelliJ IDEA F3 key functionality

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I'm confused. While in search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> iterates over the occurrences of the searched text.

Outside search, <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> iterates on some other text.

What's going on here? (Using IDEA 14). How do I determine what <kbd>F3</kbd> does outside the search context?

Answer (score 0):

Outside of a find, <kbd>F3</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> will repeat your last find operation.

If you go into the KeyMap settings, click the filter button [image], enter <kbd>F3</kbd>, then hover over the results, the tool tip show that information. It's probably in the help documents somewhere, but I did not find it (no pun intended) when I did a *quick* search.

[image]